# Changing the Git user info in Replit

Tags: git, git-config

I want to run `git commit` using a different name and email, but Replit is making me use my Replit username (it appears in the `.git/config` file). When I run this:

```
git config user.name "First Last"
```

It reverts `.git/config` to use my Replit username whenever I reload the repl. How do I prevent that?

Comment: When you make a commit, that commit contains the name and email address from your configuration (`git config --get user.name` and `git config --get user.email`). Those two entities are now part of the commit: they cannot be changed, ever, by any means. If you don't like the embedded strings, you must make a new and different commit—perhaps one with everything *else* the same as before—that embeds different strings. Meanwhile, when you run `git push`, Git *does not* use the `user.name` setting at all to accomplish the push: Git instead runs other programs that do their own things.

Comment: Meanwhile, whatever Replit is, it does not appear to be Git. Google search suggests it's an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set these environment variables: GIT_AUTHOR_NAME, GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL, GIT_COMMITTER_NAME, GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL